# How to check if string has only alpha characters and one space (Javascript)

Tags: regex

I found a way to check if a string has only one space between whatever characters.

```
if (/^[^ ]* [^ ]*$/.test(name))
```

But I want the string to contain only alpha characters between one space. I'm new to regex so I'm not sure how to do this.

I tried this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
if (/^[a-z ]* [a-z ]*$/i.test(name))
```

"John Smith" should work but something like "John W Smith" or "111 111" should not work.

Comment: I found https://regexr.com/ to be very helpful in writing regexes

Comment: Try: /[a-z]*\s[a-z]*$/      - removed some spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/^[a-zA-Z]* [a-zA-Z]*$/
```

where `[a-zA-Z]*` matches 0 or more (`*`) alphabetic characters (`a-z`) case insensitively (`a-zA-Z`). Mind that the only space is between the two capturing groups, because it needs to be matched literally. I would really recommend using https://regex101.com/ for testing your regular expressions, it saved me a lot of time.